# Which disease could be turning the leaves on my tomato plants BLUE?

Tags: identification, diseases, pests, tomatoes, fungus

The leaves are very dry (though the plants were watered regularly and consistenly), have this bluish tint and those brown spots. Googled, but found nothing, which is weird. What could this be?
[image]